# How to save a Single Packet Authorisation packet using the fwknop-client?

Tags: cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I was trying to save a SPA packet created via the fwknop-client on a client in client-server architecture.

The command that I have used is as follows
"fwknop -A tcp/22 -D server-ip --key-gen --use-hmac --save-packet --save-packet-file filename.pkt --save-rc-stanza -vv"

The command executes successfully but I'm not able to save the packet, the packet is not found in the system.

I also trying to append the packet using the "--save-packet-append" tag, but still not able to get the output.

The purpose for doing to above is to obtain the SPA packet and append the client certificate (asymmetric encryption) to this SPA packet which will be sent.

How can i save this packet to fulfil my purpose ?

Thank You

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Thanks @JamesKPolk